# Android Opencv similar picture detection

Tags: android, image, opencv, matching

I wrote an Android prototype to calculate a similarity of two pictures, using the OpenCV library.

```
    private void drawFeatureMatches(){
    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);

    //first image
    Mat img1 = Imgcodecs.imread(picturePath1);
    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

    //second image
    Mat img2 = Imgcodecs.imread(picturePath2);
    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
    descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    //matcher image descriptors
    MatOfDMatch  matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches);

    //feature and connection colors
    Scalar RED = new Scalar(255,0,0);
    Scalar GREEN = new Scalar(0,255,0);

    //output image
    Mat outputImg = new Mat();
    MatOfByte drawnMatches = new MatOfByte();
    //draw all matches
    Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches,
            outputImg, GREEN, RED, drawnMatches, Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    Bitmap imageMatched = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputImg.cols(), outputImg.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);//need to save bitmap
    Utils.matToBitmap(outputImg, imageMatched);

    ivImage3.setImageBitmap(getScaledBitmap(imageMatched));

    // calculate total number of matches and good matches
    double max_dist = 0;
    double min_dist = 100;

    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();

    // Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors2.rows(); i++ ) {
        double dist = matchesList.get(i).distance;
        if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
        if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
    }

    // calculate good matches
    LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors2.rows(); i++ )
        if( matchesList.get(i).distance <= 3*min_dist ) good_matches.addLast( matchesList.get(i));

    float percent = (100 * good_matches.size())/ matchesList.size();
    tv.setText (Html.fromHtml("good / total matches: " + good_matches.size() + " / " + matchesList.size() + " (= " + percent + "%)"));
}
```

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp690.jpg)

The left orange picture on the screenshot was taken with a slr-camera, the right one was taken with a smartphone camera and was cropped.
Although pictures are quite the same my calculated similarity is only 3%.

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzZ6R.jpg)

The second screenshot contains 2 very different pictures, the calculated similarity however is bigger here (14%).

Obviously my algorithm is wrong. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi can you please tell us what: "ivImage3" and "tv" are?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend two improvements to your algorithm:

1. In this case ORBs salient point detection approach is not a good choice. The default setting limits the maximum feature size to the 500 strongest responses. Keypoints won't be generated inside the matching areas, when other areas contain enough attractive content. Any other detection will do.
2. A simple thresholding will lower the inlier/outlier ratio of your matching but is very unreliable and unstable as a criteria. Estimating a transform (either homography or fundamental matrix) and computing an inlier/outlier ratio works better.

OpenCV already contains a function to estimate the transform
[OpenCV Documentation findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography)

The ratio is simply calculated:

[image: \frac{inliers}{features}]

with inliers being the number of features that fit your model and features being the count of all features extracted from the query image.

Comment: thanks Gilfoy. my idea is to have a database containing higher-quality images (can be paintings, can be drawings, can be photograps, ...), then i take a photograph with a smartphone and find "identical" images in the database. so which kind of detection would you recommend for my case? Could you please give details how to estimate a transform and compute the normalized inlier/outlier ratio?

Comment: some more details would be very helpful. thank you very much!